# Mercurial - Automatically collapsing commits based on message?

Tags: mercurial

If I submit two or more commits into Mercurial with the same message, is there a way to collapse these into one change-set automatically?  I assume this would have to be done in a changeset hook but I have not been able to find an automated method for this.  Most examples require knowing the changeset revision numbers to collapse it manually and I'd want a way to automatically compare the previous change with the one being submitted and "merge" the two into one changeset.

In other words:

```
hg commit -m "some change"
hg commit -m "some change"

| * 20 <- "some change"
| * 19 <- "some change"
| * ..
```

Could this automatically become one changeset and fold it with the last one with the same commit message?

```
| * 19 <- "some change"
| * ..
```

This would only collapse changes if the commit message is exactly the same and sequential.

Because I know someone will try to point to these again... I'm not looking for these extensions, but an automatic method that does not require knowing the IDs or revisions.

[ConcatenatingChangesets](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConcatenatingChangesets)

[CollapseExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension)

[HisteditExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension)

---

Would this be possible if I 'tag'ged the previous commit?  Could you combine your next commit into a tagged commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git calls this "amend" and it is a feature of the regular 'git commit' tool.  It doesn't do it based on commit message, you have to pass a '--amend' option to commit and it will combine the previous commit with the one you're creating.  I haven't tried this with mercurial, but the [GitConcepts page on the mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts) says you could run `hg rollback; hg commit -m "message"` to have the same affect.

I should warn you that rollback will rollback the most recent commit in the repository (tip), so if you have pulled changes or merged things since your last regular commit, rollback will most likely not rollback the changeset you want it to.  Additionally if you have pushed changes (or others have pulled from you) you will be breaking compatibility with those repositories because you're essentially editing history.

In theory you could write a hook which will see if the tip of the repository is on the same branch that you're on and if its commit message matches the one you're entering, and if so do a rollback and a commit in one go.

I'm curious to know what your goal is as that will help in recommending a solution for that goal.  There may be better and more elegant ways to produce the result you desire than combining changesets.  I know that you're not interested in extensions for some reason, but if you're trying to achieve a clean and logical changeset history, you should look in to the 
[MqExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).

Comment: It's not that I do not like the extensions... it's that they are a manual process.  I do not see a way to have them automatically determine if the previous commit was for the same purpose and combine the changeset into a new "cleaner" version.  Having the rollback + resubmit would work if I knew I was the last one to touch the repository, but that's not something I want to rely on.  I don't foresee why editing the branch to combine changesets would be an issue if someone else branched a changeset to merge later.  In fact, I assume it would make for faster merging.

Comment: So, I actually tried this with mercurial last night.  I had some local changes that I wanted to amend to the previous commit.  I ran 'hg rollback' and then 'hg commit' and it resulted in one commit without any errors.  I think in theory you could get conflicts at rollback-time, but I didn't experience that.

Comment: Yep, it works if you know that the last commit is something you want to manually 'undo.'  But it doesn't solve the problem of multiple small commits for the same purpose automatically.  Just as I noted with the extensions, it's a manual process.